# flexbox issue in ie 10 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

Before adding

```
display: -ms-flexbox; /* ie 10*/
-ms-flex-align: center;
```

my design was like

[image]

After adding the css above my design was broken
[image]

Here is the full code

```
.vcenter {
                                  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
                                  -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
                                  display: -ms-flexbox; /* ie 10*/
                                  -ms-flex-align: center;
                                  display: flex;
                                  align-items: center;
                                  /*border-bottom:0.5em solid White;*/
                                }
```

Comment: Was the design working correctly before the flexbox? If so, why add the flexbox to start with? What were you trying to do?

Comment: @DBS, if u take a look at the first image the current temp is moved to the top . so to fix it I had used it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ah, ok. Well I would personally try using another method of vertical centring, flexbox's are relatively unreliable in IE, even up to IE11

Comment: @DBS , any suggestions?

Comment: As these are alternatives rather than an answer, this comment may be a little cramped, but there's a few pages detailing possible methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/